# Image Processing: Extracting faint line in a noisy grayscale image

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm trying to figure out a way to automatically process this image so that I can extract all the major lines/curves later on. The main issue I'm having is getting the really faint white line on the left side of the image. I've already tried several methods which I'll detail below however many of them aren't able to get the line. Are there any possible keywords or topics I can look into for processing this image?

[image: original]

Methods:
Significance -> probability enhancement (loses detail on the line)

[image]

Significance segmentation

[image]

FFT

[image]

In the end, whenever I add on something like a canny edge detector to these images, the line on the left does not show, e.g.

[image]

Comment: You should try line detectors like the Frangi vesselness filter or the RORPO method. I implemented these in DIPlib: https://diplib.org/diplib-docs/detection_lines.html (though you’ll lilely find implementations elsewhere too).

Comment: please point this "line" out clearly. then describe *what* is being imaged and how it is being imaged. -- does that date code mean 1980? is that accurate?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77706097/ways-to-get-a-precise-continous-mapping-between-synthetic-images-and-real-images